# DeploymentException: WELD-001408 on injection when using extended classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

I have the following DBOs:

```
public abstract class DetailDbo{
    ....
}

public abstract class MasterDbo<T>{
    ....
}

public class B extends DetailDbo{
    ....
}

public class A extends MasterDbo<B>{
    ....
}
```

My service:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyService<T extends MasterDbo<D>, D extends DetailDbo>{
    //implemetation
}
```

My bean:

```
public class MyBean<T extends MasterDbo<D>, D extends DetailDbo>{

    @Inject
    protected MyService<T, D>   ws;

    ...
}
```

Extended bean:

```
SpecialBean extends MyBean<A, B>{
    //implemetation
}
```

At the injection point I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyService<A, B>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject protected com.xxx.xx.MyBean.ws]
```

**Why am I getting this error?**

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulation ! You've just discovered a bug in Weld : https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1855

While waiting for the fix, you can use this workaround. Change your EJB to :

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyService<T extends MasterDbo<? extends DetailDbo>, D extends DetailDbo>{
    //implemetation
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Hmm, no even that works, unfortunately I had to change it to : `public class MyService<T extends MasterDbo<?>, D extends DetailDbo>{`

Comment: I create a test on github and it works with WildFly 8.2.0 (weld 2.2.6). You can test it by you self : clone https://github.com/antoinesd/CDI-Sandbox and launch `mvn clean test -Pweld-2.2` or  `mvn clean test -Pwildlfy-8`.

Comment: Must be my version (WELD 1.1.17)